# Cannot change value of key in an object with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am unable to change the value of a key in an object with typescript. These are the types

```typescript
export enum FOO_TYPES {
    red = "red",
    green = "green"
}

export type FooTypes = {
    [key in keyof typeof FOO_TYPES]: boolean
}

enum SOME_OTHER_ENUM {
    a = "abc",
    d = "def", 
    e = "ghi"
}

export interface SomeMoreData {
    id: number,
    key: SOME_OTHER_ENUM,
    priceA: number,
    priceB: number,
    red: boolean,
    green: boolean,
}

type ProjectProps = {
    [key in SOME_OTHER_ENUM]?: {
        project: SomeMoreData ,
        amountPriceAPriceB: {
            sumPriceA: number;
            sumPriceB: number;
        }
    }
}

interface GroupedProjectProps {
    [FOO_TYPES.red]: ProjectProps,
    [FOO_TYPES.green]: ProjectProps
};
```

Now I am having this function

```typescript
const someFunc = (projects: GroupedProjectProps) => {
    const availableTypes: FooTypes = {
        red: false,
        green: false
    };

    (Object.keys(projects) as Array<keyof typeof FOO_TYPES >).map(type => {
        if (Object.keys(projects[type]).length > 0)  availableTypes[type] = true
    })
}
```

Which gives me the following error

> Cannot assign to 'red' because it is a read-only property.
>
> Cannot assign to 'green' because it is a read-only property.

Which I do not understand why this error is coming up...
Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4UwDwBwewJwC7gHYFcC2wBiB5HB9AFQE0AFAUQGVgBvAWAChRng4wATYAXmACI32vADSMWoAOZswybn0lhpvUaAC%20ykOvDR4SBAE8oYbDBiEDYAM6z6TMcADaAazB7gASxnO9MAGbB9hr7YeERkVAC6AFzAAEYmADZgAIbImmq2GhkoGMCUOACy5Pg4hAAS5ABK%20OQAcgCq%20bSazEmyvEkxAMbCzaCcPLzsYD7CwL0gRgPiABZuSlnpzJqQsIjuyAhgcD5JnUaUMOhg%20fBgACJJCK02du7s0WjoMVsiWcxe0XmFxWWV1fX5V63KBwNx7ACCDwwzzgQLsILBYAAQlCni9xqwONE4jBEik4WJ5NJsQlksgCcBFqBNAEjKQ4DAAFZgToIekwKBWHg3OxOFzrXIFIolcpVWoNcIAfmiPNuIBBTJZCE%20h2OpwuV2AFNuSXQMFQG3piPBRr2KKabzlIAsGFNYEhwEeMIA3Bjbjb0HbzU6tq7LWIqQG0ppNB5NttdkYAOIM1CGdjs5ms9mci23ey4AgkCiUAB0AiiwETSpTFm1oAzIWzVFzROQheLyYZnLSfsYmk6MGQFiQFlVWANnVkAAoFUmEBZojH9fHG2zmxYAJTcAB8absne7SCSADckm54h1EmZDJPjKZzFz11aBNEdvELGBy4SpMg70kH2AMSo2-7gMOcBicdcy8CxRwZccl2AJIrHBOA4CSPQAB4vCCWkgkzUIc2AFdF1zdAkigYdaVXa85TcPwAKApUQJcMCxyVCx7FpcI8MSZBxAQaYcOAAAGZdoL3A8jzAE9LGY8xwlkBA4FQL8GG-RcQwWIA)

```typescript
(Object.keys(projects) as Array<keyof typeof FOO_TYPES >).map(type=> {
    const a = projects[compensateType]
    if (Object.keys(a).length > 0)  availableTypes[type] = true
})
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that your `FooTypes` has readonly properties.

```ts
export type FooTypes = {
  [key in keyof typeof FOO_TYPES]: boolean
}

/**
type FooTypes = {
  readonly red: boolean;
  readonly green: boolean;
}
*/
```

See [readonly modifier for properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#readonly-and-const)

You can use [Mapping Modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to make the properties mutable

```ts
export type FooTypes = {
  -readonly [key in keyof typeof FOO_TYPES]: boolean
}

/**
type FooTypes = {
  red: boolean;
  green: boolean;
}
*/
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4UwDwBwewJwC7gHYFcC2wBiB5HB9AFQE0AFAUQGVgBvAWAChRng4wATYAXmACI32vADSMWoAOZswybn0lhpvUaAC%20ykOvDR4SBAE8oYbDBiEDYAM6z6TFgFo2AQ3YxkAGz3AA2gGswngEsZPz0YADNgfUNw7DwiMioAXQAuYAAjEzcwR2RNNVsNApQMYEocAFlyfBxCAAlyACV8cgA5AFVy2k1mR1leRzSAY2Fu0E4eXnYwMOFgUZAjCfEACwClIvzmTUhYRGAghDA4MMdBo0oYdDBy%20DAAEUcEXpsxEAD2VLR0NKORIuYQqkypVqnVGs12uU-q9gFA4AEzgBBT4YH5waGvOEIsAAIRR31%2081YHFSGRgWRyGLE8mkpMy2WQVOAm1AmiiRlIcBgACswIMEJyYFArDwXq9fP59jJgVUavUmq0OokAPypMUwkBwnl8hBAy7XW4PJ7AJkwxzoGCoZAC%20FIznYvFdf4akAWDD2pH4tEAbiJMLd6A9uK9R19zrELIjeU0mgORxOZ2AAHEuahDOxBbz%20YLhU6YV5cAQSBRKAA6AQpYCZnU5iym0AFuLFqilmnISvV7Nc4V5MOMTSDVwWJAWfVYK2DWQACi1WYQFlSKct6c7NqFFgAlNwAHx516D5DD4COABujgCbgGWTMhgXxlM5hFe5dAlSJzcFjA9epUmQb8cH5gESKh9uGwBTjgaRzqWIQWDOXJzpux5WIicBwI4egADwhDE7IxIW8QlsA24bqW6COFAU7sjuz4agEEQQVBOowf4cGzjqFheOyiSkVkyDiAgyzEcAAAMW7HmeF5XmAN6WFx5iJLICBwKgQEMMBG4xhsQA)

Comment: But what I do not understand: I do not want to mutate the key, only the value of the key...

Comment: You are doing the assignment in this line: `availableTypes[type] = true`

Comment: Changed the wording and added link to docs on readonly modifier for properties.

Comment: Hm, it works but I still do not understand why. When I create an object like this `const myObject = {name: "Maria"}` then I can do a `myObject.name = "John"` which works. That works in TypeScript as well. Why do I have to assign the `-readonly` modifier?

Comment: You assigned an explicit type to `availableTypes`: `const availableTypes: FooTypes`. FooTypes had readonly properties. To use your example, it is sth like `const myObject: {readonly name: string} = {name: "Maria"}`. Properties in `FooTypes` are readonly because it is a mapped type based on `FOO_TYPES`, and properties in `FOO_TYPES` are readonly.